# How to search key phrases in a pdf and extract that paragraph

Tags: python-3.x

I have thousands of annual reports (PDF format). Also, I have a list of key phrases such as "company was fined", "worse emissions standards", "fined for environment violation"...etc.

My goal is to search the key phrases in those PDF files and extract the paragraph.

I am able to do this by using single word key word like "fined", "worse" but not able to do this with multiple words in single phrase.

The below is my code ( Please Help!)

## function to flag sentences that include default vocabulary.

```
def relevant_date_default(text_arg):
    default_jargon = set()
    default_jargon = {"censure any person", "Violed", "bribery"}
    text_arg_new = text_arg.lower()
    for phrase in default_jargon:
        if phrase in text_arg_new:
            return True
    return False
```

Please help me with this, I am really stuck on this since long.

Comment: tried `any()` or `all()`? e.g. `any(w in text for w in words)`, with `words` being a list of words to search for in `text`